# Algorithmic help needed (N bags and items distributed randomly)

Tags: algorithm

I have encountered an algorithmic problem but am not able to figure out anything better than brute force or reduce it to a better know problem. Any hints?

There are N bags of variable sizes and N types of items. Each type of items belongs to one bag. There are lots of items of each type and each item may be of a different size. Initially, these items are distributed across all the bags randomly. We have to place the items in their respective bags. However, we can only operate with a pair of bags at one time by exchanging items <s>(as much as possible)</s> and proceeding to the next pair. <s>The aim is to reduce the total number of pairs.</s> **Edit: The aim is to find a sequence of transfers that minimizes the total number of bag pairs involved**

**Clarification**:

The bags are not arbitrarily large (You can assume the bag and item sizes to be integers between 0 to 1000 if it helps). You'll frequently encounter scenarios where  the all the items between 2 bags cannot be swapped due to the limited capacity of one of the bags. This is where the algorithm needs to make an optimisation. Perhaps, if another pair of bags were swapped first, the current swap can be done in one go. To illustrate this, let's consider Bags A, B and C and their items 1, 2, 3 respectively. The number in the brackets is the size.

A(10) : 3(8)

B(10): 1(2), 1(3)

C(10): 1(4)

The swap orders can be AB, AC, AB or AC, AB. The latter is optimal as the number of swaps is lesser.

Comment: Does the answer need to be exact?

Comment: It seems to like a sorting problem and as per condition i think you can use something like merge sort to arrange items in their respective bags.

Comment: Do bags have a limit on the net size of the items they can contain?

Comment: Richard, an approximate answer is also fine. Please share your approach. Each bag has fixed capacity as I've mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: Subro, how will sorting the items by size in their respective bags help minimize the number of exchanges? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @rhino2rhonda: Any limits on the size of the bags or the items? I'm assuming all sizes are positive. But perhaps there are maximum sizes? Perhaps the minimum sizes are greater than zero? Perhaps the sizes must be integers? (Please respond using `@Richard`, so I get a notification that you've done so.)

Comment: @Richard, I see your concern. I have added the assumptions and an example to clarify. Please see my last edit.

Comment: Could you please clarify your example? I don't see the item 2 there.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, Yes, item 2 is not present in the example. All items would typically be present in all the bags but I just wanted to illustrate how the order of swaps is relevant. If we first swap bags A and B, we will be able to move only 1 item (Item 1 with size 2) from B to A. We will then have to perform swap AC to make room in bag A and then swap AB again to transfer the second item from B to A. So, 3 swaps in all. If we instead choose to swap bags A and B first, there would be enough room in bag A to complete the AB swap in one go and so only 2 swaps are required in all. Hope that explains.

Comment: @rhino2rhonda Is an answer only valid if all items are in their respective bags or would you say if 99% of the items are in their respective bags it would be a very good solution still? You said the number of swaps is okay when approximated, so Im asking if the fitness of the solution is also fine if approximated?

Comment: A few questions: a) are all items of one class guaranteed to fit in their bag? b) is it possible to assume an infinite "outside" bag for temporal storage? c) is it guaranteed that there is always a solution? (I think if the answers to a) and b) are "yes" the this will automatically be true too, although I'm not sure if b) is necessary).

Comment: @Glubus, all the items must be sorted correctly, no approximation there.

Comment: @jdehesa, Yes, a solution is guaranteed and additional space is not available. You can ignore the scenarios that have no solution (and hence require additional space). You can also assume that all the items of each class will fit in their respective bags.

Comment: @rhino2rhonda I see, thanks. Can you please clarify what you mean by "swap"? In English, swap means exchanging one thing for another (something goes from A to B *and* something goes from B to A. But are you implying that a "swap" can mean moving items only from *one* bag to another?

Comment: @גלעדברקן You are right, "swap" is misleading. We can call it "transfer" instead. Typically, there would be content to "swap" in most bag pairs, hence I used the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot come to an idea for an algorithm that will always find an optimal answer, and approximation of the fitness of the solution (amount of swaps) is also fine, I suggest a stochastic local search algorithm with pruning.

Given a random starting configuration, this algorithm considers all possible swaps, and makes a weighed decision based on chance: the better a swap is, the more likely it is chosen.

The value of a swap would be the sum of the value of the transaction of an item, which is zero if the item does not end up in it's belonging bag, and is positive if it does end up there. The value increases as the item's size increases (the idea behind this is that a larger block is *hard* to move many times in comparison to smaller blocks). This fitness function can be replaced by any other fitness function, it's efficiency is unknown until empirically shown.

Since any configuration can be the consequence of many preceding swaps, we keep track of which configurations we have seen before, along with a fitness (based on how many items are in their correct bag - this fitness is not related to the value of a swap) and the list of preceded swaps. If the fitness function for a configuration is the sum of the items that are in their correct bags, then the amount of items in the problem is the highest fitness (and therefor marks a configuration to be a solution).

A swap is *not* possible if:

- Either of the affected bags is holding more than it's capacity after the potential swap.
- The new swap brings you back to  the last configuration you were in before the last swap you did (i.e. reversed swap).

When we identify potential swaps, we look into our list of previously seen configurations (use a hash function for `O(1)` lookup). Then we either set its preceded swaps to our preceded swaps (if our list is shorter than it's), or we set our preceded swaps to its list (if it's list is shorter than ours). We can do this because it does not matter which swaps we did, as long as the amount of swaps is as small as possible.

If there are no more possible swaps left in a configuration, it means you're stuck. Local search tells you 'reset' which you can do in may ways, for instance:

- Reset to a previously seen state (maybe the best one you've seen so far?)
- Reset to a new valid random solution

### Note

- Since the algorithm only allows you to do valid swaps, all constraints will be met for each configuration.
- The algorithm does not guarantee to 'stop' out of the box, you can implement a maximum number of iterations (swaps)
- The algorithm does not guarantee to find a correct solution, as it does it's best to find a better configuration each iteration. However, since a perfect solution (set of swaps) should look closely to an almost perfect solution, a human might be able to finish what the local search algorithm was not after it results in a invalid configuration (where not every item is in its correct bag).
- The used fitness functions and strategies are very likely not the most efficient out there. You could look around to find better ones. A more efficient fitness function / strategy should result in a good solution faster (less iterations).

Comment: Thanks, it'll take me some time to digest all of this but I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: If you need more help / explanations you can ask here, I usually check stackoverflow